OriginalRepliedMessageSid field is missing in twilio whatsapp response body webhook?
I'm making a POST request to receive inbound WhatsApp messages from the Twilio webhook (using the Twilio sandbox). When I reply to a message sent from the Twilio WhatsApp number to my WhatsApp number, I expect to see the OriginalRepliedMessageSid field in the body. This field helps us retrieve the original message that is being replied to. However, I don't see this field in the body I receive from the Twilio webhook. Does the sandbox environment omit fields like this?
I receive this body:


{
  SmsMessageSid: 'SM329cc4a27d05a24d83e8ad2f0cdbebf5',
  NumMedia: '0',
  ProfileName: 'My name',
  MessageType: 'text',
  SmsSid: 'SM329cc4a27d05a24d83e8ad2f0cdbebf5',
  WaId: '84913289351',
  SmsStatus: 'received',
  Body: 'reply message 4',
  To: 'whatsapp:twiliotestnumber',
  NumSegments: '1',
  ReferralNumMedia: '0',
  MessageSid: 'SM329cc4a27d05a24d83e8ad2f0cdbebf5',
  AccountSid: 'AC98b7b479eabe2d1622389faebb93e666',
  From: 'whatsapp:mynumber',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01'
}



I expect to have field OriginalRepliedMessageSid in this body:
Twilio docs

You are right, this is a limitation we currently have in our sandbox. Sorry for the inconvenience.
However,  it will work exactly like that once you leave the sandbox environment and start using a production-ready sender.

Thank you! I’m concerned that this field might not appear when my project is deployed to production. My backend code will still attempt to retrieve this field and perform a check. Is that possible?

The field will definitely be there for non-sandbox scenarios

Having said that, your code should still check if the field is present because it, by definition, optional. WhatsApp users might decide to send a new message without replying to an existing one. And then, you won't receive that field.

My system is similar to a CRM system. Each venue registered on our platform can access the WhatsApp messaging feature. I want to know how they can verify their WhatsApp number in our Twilio console and send messages to their customers using their own WhatsApp number. Do I need to manually add their WhatsApp numbers to our Twilio console?

This sounds like a separate discussion. Could you please open a new question for this? But maybe this page already helps you as well.
